# How to perform a logic when spring boot app starts?

Tags: java, spring, service

I am making a simple golf game. where there are 2 golf courses, when running the program I want the 2 golf courses added to the DB. I am using service and repository and endpoints for the golfers so new golfers can be added. but for the golf courses that have 3 holes each, **I want them to be added automatically when the program runs**. I have tried this:

Below is my code snippet. I want to execute *addGolfCoursesAtStart()* when my app is launched.

```
    @Autowired
    GolfCourseService gcs;
    
    public void addGolfCoursesAtStart() {
        // create course 1
        GolfCourse gc1 = new GolfCourse("Happy Gilmore", 220, 300, 50);
        System.out.println("we created a golf course for you named: " +gc1.getName());
        System.out.println("this course has the following holes:");
        for (Hole hole : gc1.getHoles()) {
            System.out.println(hole.getName());
            System.out.println("length: " + hole.getLenthHole());
        }
        
        gcs.addGolfCourse(gc1);
        System.out.println("\n\n");
    }
```

How would I achieve that?

Comment: can you post the error. Without seeing the error I can't say what is the problem in your code. May be  `gcs` will be null

Comment: "i want them to be added automatically when the program runs" -  Does this mean you want to add Golf courses before every test case ? or you want to add the golf courses in db when the spring boot app starts?

Comment: @AbhinabaChakraborty i want to add the golf courses in db when the spring boot app starts

Comment: @deadshot:
HAVE A GOOD DAY AT THE GOLF COURSE


we created a golf course for you named: Happy Gilmore
this course has the following holes:
hole 1
length: 0
hole 2
length: 0
hole 3
length: 0
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.golfgame.domain.Test.addGolfCoursesAtStart(Test.java:23)
 at com.golfgame.GolfgameApplication.main(GolfgameApplication.java:20)

Comment: @MauriceDibbets please check my answer. What I feel is, you need to make use of Spring Events.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add the golf courses in db when the spring boot app starts,
you need to listen to the **ApplicationReadyEvent** of Spring and put your logic there.

There are other events too that Spring, by default, provides us to hook into the application context lifecycle , like:

1. **ContextRefreshedEvent**
2. **ContextStartedEvent**
3. **ContextStoppedEvent**
4. **ContextClosedEvent**
5. **RequestHandledEvent**
   etc etc

You can read more about them in the official Spring docs.

Here is the code using **ApplicationReadyEvent**:

```
@Component
public class MyApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

  @Autowired
  GolfCourseService gcs;

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {

    //Your spring boot app is initialzied and application is ready
    addGolfCoursesAtStart();

  }

  public void addGolfCoursesAtStart() {
    // create course 1
    GolfCourse gc1 = new GolfCourse("Happy Gilmore", 220, 300, 50);
    System.out.println("we created a golf course for you named: " +gc1.getName());
    System.out.println("this course has the following holes:");
    for (Hole hole : gc1.getHoles()) {
      System.out.println(hole.getName());
      System.out.println("length: " + hole.getLenthHole());
    }

    gcs.addGolfCourse(gc1);
    System.out.println("\n\n");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you annotate your test class with @ContextConfiguration and then run. Autowiring will not work unless the context is loaded .